# How to get a true when a character is NOT in range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter, regex

I want to filter all cells in a range which are not empty and does not contain a certain character. So I tried everything with `regexmatch`

```
=filter(Planning!G$5:G$37; regexmatch(Planning!G$5:G$37 ; "![a]"))
```

---

```
=filter(Planning!G$5:G$37; regexmatch(Planning!G$5:G$37 ; "<>a"))
```

---

```
=filter(Planning!G$5:G$37; regexmatch(Planning!G$5:G$37 ; "\a"))
```

but not even my simplified formula where I cut out the " ! not empty" part, doesn't give me any result.

My question: So what is the proper way to show the cells that don't contain the letter 'a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:A10, "where not A contains 'a' and A is not null")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We usually don't have to conceptualize it this way, but in the "conditions" part of `FILTER`, we're actually setting up an array of `TRUE` or `FALSE` results to control whether each input row makes it through the filter. Perhaps take advantage of that and negate the Booleans outside the `REGEXMATCH`?

```
=FILTER(Planning!G$5:G$37; NOT(REGEXMATCH(Planning!G$5:G$37; "a")))
```

That `REGEXMATCH` silently errors out on-text values, so I'd also convert to `TEXT` before the check.

```
=FILTER(Planning!G$5:G$37; NOT(REGEXMATCH(TEXT(Planning!G$5:G$37;); "a")))
```

Lastly a side note, formulas that work on arrays don't work with the native boolean `OR` and `AND` functions, but we can instead use `+` and `*` respectively. This formula requires `FILTER` matches to `NOT` pass the `REGEXMATCH`, `AND` to have non-zero `LEN` (length):

```
=FILTER(Planning!G$5:G$37; NOT(REGEXMATCH(TEXT(Planning!G$5:G$37;); "a")) * LEN(Planning!G$5:G$37))
```

…if that better suits your actual spreadsheet and formulas rather than just having a second `FILTER` condition:

```
=FILTER(Planning!G$5:G$37; NOT(REGEXMATCH(TEXT(Planning!G$5:G$37;); "a")), LEN(Planning!G$5:G$37))
```